# Como posso receber nomes através de um campo de texto em uma página HTML e salvá-los em um vetor no Local Storage do navegador?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Preciso de ajuda para terminar a lógica da função:

```html
<form name="form1" onsubmit="submeter()">

    Nome: <input type="text" id="nome" value="" onkeyup="validarNome()"/><br/><br/>
    Idade: <input type="text" id="idade" value="" onkeyup="validarIdade()"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar" onclick="salvar()"/><br/><br/>

</form>

<script>
    function salvar(){
        var Nomes = new Array();
        Nomes[i] = document.getElementById("nome").value;

    localStorage["Nomes"] = JSON.stringify(Nomes);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Descreva melhor o seu problema/necessidade.

Comment: Preciso de um código em javascript que salve todos os dados de nome em um vetor e os dados de idade em outro vetor no Local Storage. E que ao fazer um novo cadastro, os dados antigos não sejam apagados, e sim acumulados no vetor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de evitar que a `form` faça submit para o servidor. Podes fazer isso com `<input type="submit" value="Salvar" onclick="return salvar()" />` no HTML e tendo `return false;` no final da função `salvar`.

De resto o teu código estava quase lá. Uma versão mais flexivel, onde vai buscar e salvar todos os campos que tenham o atributo `name` seria assim:

```js
function salvar() {
    var inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('form input[name]'));
    var data = {};
    inputs.forEach(function(input) {
        data[input.name] = input.value;
    });
    localStorage.meusDados = JSON.stringify(data);
    document.querySelector('form').reset();
    return false;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xaveqfax/

Comment: obrigado, mas eu queria que as informações ficassem acumuladas em vetor, e não apaguem assim que salvar um novo dado.

Comment: @Pedro isso é simples, então queres uma array/vetor onde cada entrada é um objeto com os dados dos inputs que tiveres?

Comment: Sim. Um array que vai acumular todos os nomes e outro que vai acumular todos as idades.

Comment: Preciso de um código em javascript que salve todos os dados de nome em um vetor e os dados de idade em outro vetor no Local Storage. E que ao fazer um novo cadastro, os dados antigos não sejam apagados, e sim acumulados no vetor. Poderia fazer por favor?

Comment: @Pedro então queres algo como isto: https://jsfiddle.net/j5chv3r2/

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream('array.txt');
file.on('Erro', function(err) { /* houve um erro */ });
arr.forEach(function(v) { file.write(v.join(', ') + '\n'); });
file.end();
```

ou

```
require("fs").writeFile(
     somepath,
     arr.map(function(v){ return v.join(', ')).join('\n'),
     function (err) { console.log(err ? 'Error :'+err : 'ok' }
);
```

Comment: Acho que o que o autor da pergunta (AP) procura é uma solução no browser, não em Node.js

Comment: Ai complica :3.

Comment: @KlanPaia o localStorage não estaria para simplificar?